# C++ class methods forward declaration

Tags: c++, cyclic-reference

Is there any way to redeclare a class to define methods which where only declared this far?

Eg. something like:

```
class A
{
    void a();
    void b() {}
}

class A
{
    void a() {}
}
```

instead of

```
class A
{
    void a();
    void b() {}
}

A::a() {}
```

The reason is I created a lot of code with methods defined inside the class defintion, without using headers. I do not had cyclic references up to now, but recently there is need to. I don't like to define bunches of methods by the `Type::method` syntax, as only very few methods have to be known before the latter definition of the class.

So I like somewhat like a `backward declaration`, declare or define only a few methods before for cyclic references and define the whole class later.

Comment: Once a class-type is closed by `}` it *cannot* be opened again. The closed definition is *the* definition for the translation unit. Are you sure you aren't just in need of a namespace instead?

Comment: Header files, Type::method , namespace are the ways of this in **C++**, for all of us. If you don't like it , switch language to something newer , like python. You will get rid of all that declarations, size of your code will get few times smaller.

Comment: I just reimplement a project I've done in Java some years ago.. so the language is well chosen I guess. I need the performance benefits of template-defined stack allocated objects.

Comment: This is a no-starter, but maybe if you show the kind of problem you are trying to fix with some small sample code, people might be able to suggest viable solutions.

Comment: You can define functions inline after the class declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to redefine a class.

According to the C++ language standard the class definitions is:

```
class-specifier:
    class-head { member-specification_opt }
```

The standard explicitly says that member specification should be complete within class definition:

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and enumerators. The member-specification in a class definition declares the full set of members of the class; **no member can be added elsewhere**.

Also the standard gives example of redefinition of class:

> ```
> struct S { int a; };
> struct S { int a; }; // error, double definition
> ```
>
> is **ill-formed** because it defines S twice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to declare the class again once it is Closed with `}`.

Only thing you can do is you can inherit and define the method.

```
class B : public A { a() {} } ;
```